# Does Entity Framework have a provider for Intersystems Cache?

Tags: entity-framework, intersystems-cache

If so, any drawbacks?  Any experience using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at the moment.  Microsoft has a list of [the third-party data providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dd363565.aspx) that can be used with the Entity Framework, but InterSystems Cache is currently not one of them.

The amount of developers that use both EF and Cache is probably relatively small and hasn't warranted InterSystems' investment of resources into it yet, but feel free to let your InterSystems support representative know that you're interested in having them develop a .NET data provider.  If enough people push for it, it could become a reality!